# Association between 2 tables doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR and I want to create simple page like a task manager (to add and remove tasks) so I created 2 tables with association between them (Track and Item).
Here is 2 models:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :track, optional: :true
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And I need to set association when I create or delete any track item. But when I create it I just see my track item (with an empty field in associated table)

```
For example: 
rails c
Track.create(item: 'Asafa Pauel', description: 'This is a description') - works fine (added all field to db)
Item.all - track_id field is empty - but it should show id of track item. Why is this?
```

And my Tracks controller:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @track = Track.all
  end

  def show
    @track = Track.all
  end

  def new
    @track = Track.new
  end

  def create
    @track = Track.new(track_params)
    @item = Item.new(track_id: @track.id)
    if @track.save! && @item.save!
      flash[:success] = "It works!"
      redirect_to tracks_path
    else
      flash[:success] = "Its wrong!"
    end
  end

private
  def track_params
    params.require(:track).permit(:item, :description)
  end
end
```

And Items controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
  end

  private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:track_id)
  end
end
```

And db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_05_23_112947) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "track_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["track_id"], name: "index_items_on_track_id"
  end

  create_table "tracks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "item"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the `items` table for? `Track` appears to have an attribute of `item` and many `items` which is just the `track_id` are you sure that this is what you intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new 'Track' object doesn't have an ID yet, so you can't assign its value to Item.track_id.

First you'll have to save the Track, then create a new Item.

Also, if you create a new Track from console, you won't trigger your "create" method in the controller: it will be called only if you create a new Track from browser.
If you want to create a new Item every time you create a Track, you'll have to do something like this in your model file "track.rb":

```
after_save :create_new_item

def create_new_item
    self.items.create
end
```

P.S.: the "track.rb" file is in "app/models" in your Rails application.

Comment: Thank you very much, It helped)